# How to terminate previously occupied port in macOs terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend, web-development-server

I am learning node js in macOs but I am constantly getting error like

> listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use 127.0.0.1:2300<

Comment: Find the process that's using the port then kill it.

Answer (score 1):

First you must to know the *PID* of what you're looking to kill:

`sudo lsof -i :2300`

And then kill it with this command:

`kill -9 <PID>`

PLEASE NOTE: -9 kills the process immediately, and gives it no chance of cleaning up after itself.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the process that's using the port then kill it. To find the process use the following command:

```
lsof -i -P
```

The `-i` flag displays only IP connections and the `-P` flag prints the port as numbers (instead of name, eg `443` instead of `https`).

You can filter the result using `grep`:

```
lsof -i -P | grep 2300
```

The first column is the program/command name and the second column is the process id. For example, if you get the following result:

```
myProgram   12345  ajit  5u IPv4 0xbb6307766636b4b9 0t0 TCP *:2300 (LISTEN)
```

You can `kill` the process:

```
kill 12345
```